# Initialize a class instance?

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to initialize an instance of class `consoleDroid` with `consoleDroid console = new consoleDroid();`, but it throws a `class, interface, or enum expected` compile error. What's the right way to initialize the class?

**caseSelector.java:**

```
package com.caseselector;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;

consoleDroid console = new consoleDroid();

public class caseSelector extends Activity
{
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        console.create();
    }
}
```

**consoleDroid.java:**

```
package com.caseselector;

import android.view.View;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Button;

public class consoleDroid {

    private static String output;
    private Button consoleButton;
    private TextView consoleView;
    private EditText consoleInput;

    public static void create() {
    }

    public static void write(String input) {
    }

    public static void writeLine(String input) {
    }

    public static String readLine(boolean print) {
        return output;
    }
}
```

Comment: This might have been mentioned already, but class names should always begin with a capital letter in Java.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just move your instantiation down into the class body:

```
public class caseSelector extends Activity
{
    consoleDroid console = new consoleDroid();
    // ...
}
```

Btw: by convention class names should start with a capital letter.

Answer (score 5):

You have to do instantiation inside a class. And Java classes look nicer if they start with Upper case letters.

```
public class caseSelector extends Activity
{
    consoleDroid console = new consoleDroid();

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    ....
}
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all, by convention classes should start with a capital letter. And the answer to your question - `consoleDroid console = new consoleDroid();` is not at an appropriate place. It must be somewhere inside a class - a method or a constructor.

Answer (score 1):

Your code is not in the class.
put

```
consoleDroid console = new consoleDroid();
```

inside a class...